# Replacement conversion from HTML text to graphical text

Tags: php, xml, html, graphics

I want to create a HTML/PHP page with unpredictable HTML output. Then I want to convert some of the HTML text (not the tags) to graphical text - to make the text readable but not copy-pastable !!

I am using own PHP code and maybe MySQL to do the conversion...
The page is still going to output HTML - not PDF or CSS or otherwise

I will appreciate if you can tell me where on the net to download free simple, easy-readable, graphical single-letters to replace the HTML text so that it is not copy-pastable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly possible. You can only prevent copy&past if you uses images, but however this is not really html only as you wrote.

A funny idea would be to use custom fonts (more exactly a custom web font). There you could mix up happily all chars so you could create a readable page, but it would be garbrage if you copy&past it without using your custom font. This will not work on browsers which does not support it.

Another idea would be to use canvas. There you could write any text you like which is not selectable. Also this does not work on every browser and also this requires JavaScript, which could been disabled.

However all this ideas could be broken using a screenshot and optical character recognition (OCR). Always keep in mind if there is something to see on the screen it can been copied.